# How to install TeX on Android phones?

Tags: xetex, installing, android

I used [VerbTeX](https://www.verbosus.com/android-latex-editor.html) app in my Android phone. But this app does not support XeLaTeX and requires an internet connection to be used.

Is there any distribution of TeX for Android?
How I can install TeX on my Android phone?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just have a look here: [TexPortal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lah.texportal&hl=de). This is an App for Android which runs fine on my Nexus 7 without the need for rooting my device (this was important for me). If you download all the packages you don't need an internet connection to compile the documents. Most of the time I use it just for short letters, but for testing I compiled my diploma and my master thesis with this App without any trouble.

Comment: From what I understand TeXPortal does not support XeLaTeX. Is this correct?

Comment: I just replaced the link does not work and the additional information that [texportal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lah.texportal.donate) is no longer free.

Comment: I'd classify writing LaTeX on a phone straight under "extremely cruel and unusual punishment"... and if you add a Bluetooth keyboard to make it halfway practical, a mini-notebook (or even an by now outdated netbook) looks much more alluring.

Answer (score 46):

I am the author of [TeXLive for Android](http://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/).
I have provided an `.apk` file for Android, but I have not added `XeTeX` to my app, due to the large size of the xetex binary.
You can get `XeTeX` from here: http://texlive-for-android.googlecode.com/files/tl4a-2013-06-18.tar.xz.
I am now testing my GUI of tlmgr, which is written completely in Java.

The next version of my App will add `biber` and `Vim 7.4` in 2014.
A TeX editor for my App is now under development.

Comment: Does anyone have a working `/sdcard/texlive/texmf.cnf` they could share? Also what part exactly of the texlive distribution should be copied into `/sdcard/texlive`? Perhaps someone could share the output of `ls /sdcard/texlive` from a working installation?

Comment: @flamingpenguin You can modify a `texmf.cnf` which have already installed in your computer. And then move this `texmf.cnf` to `/sdcard/texlive`. On my computer, this `texmf.cnf` file can be found in `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\web2c\texmf.cnf`. What you should do is changing the value of `TEXMFROOT`. Please read the comments in the `texmf.cnf` carefully.

Comment: OK, that worked great. I just did a portable installation of texlive into /usr/local/texlive/2013 on my linux machine. (I left out the source and docs for diskspace). Then I "rsync" the whole /usr/local/texlive/2013 into /sdcard/texlive on my asus tf700 (using the terminal IDE app from app store) and copied the texmf.cnf you mention into /sdcard/texlive and change the TEXMFROOT to /sdcard/texlive and then everything worked (although no arm biber bins are available so I have to use bibtex). Builds my complicated beamer pdfs perfectly. Awesome, thanks.

Comment: @flamingpenguin It's my pleasure. I found that the biber program in TUG's SVN is existed in binary file. I have not get sources in the SVN. I need have a look at [biber](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/), then port it to Android.

Comment: @clerk-ma TeX Live for Android does not work on Android 5. It produces an error: `error: only position independent executables (PIE) are supported.` If you have some time, please, recompile the app with PIE support. This way it will work on Android 5.

Comment: For some reason, I tried to do this in Windows using Bluestacks. Based on http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2292232, I put a TeXLive folder in `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder\` . By using ES File Explorer, I found a TeXLive folder in `mnt/sdcard/bstfolder/BstSharedFolder/TeXLive` . How to modify a `texmf.cnf`?

Answer (score 40):

There is work to implement [TeXLive 2012 for Android](http://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/). The development site provides information on progress as well as access to downloads. The code is still experimental but might be worth a try. Otherwise the existing solutons are similar to VerbTeX and may involve web-based LaTeX processing.

Comment: Ooh must try that...

Answer (score 10):

Just providing a little more detailed howto for this... I just installed texlive 2013 on my Asus TF201 and I am now able to generate PDF using `beamer`, `tikz`, `pgfplots`, `bibtex`, etc. on my tablet :)

In a few steps:

1. Download and make a "portable" installation of texlive on another computer.
2. Zip the created folder (2.1Gb for full LaTeX) and transfer to your android device.
3. Unzip folder to `/sdcard/texlive`
4. Copy the `texmf.cnf` from `/sdcard/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c` to `/sdcard/texlive`
5. Change in this file TEXMFROOT to `/sdcard/texlive`
6. Install [TeXLive for Android](http://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/) and click "Install TexLive" (generates binaries, e.g. `latex`, `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, etc.)
7. Enjoy :)

Comment: Just for information: it didn't work on my machines (slackware 12.2 - i386, android 4.3 on galaxy note II); step 6. was unsuccessful. Even tried multi.

Comment: I had some trouble getting this to work as well but managed after quite lot of experimenting. I was missing valid formats (i.e. "pdflatex.fmt") and had to generete these in my tablet. To generate a format file, use: `pdflatex -ini -output-directory=/sdcard/texlive -jobname=pdflatex latex.ltx`  (`latex.ltx` is situated in the folder texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base, with a texmf.cnf file as above, TL4A finds it). You can then generate pdfs with `pdflatex -fmt=/sdcard/texlive/pdflatex.fmt -output-format=pdf -output-directory=/sdcard/some_path /sdcard/path_to_texfile`

Answer (score 6):

It's also possible to install texlive through the Linux terminal emulator app [Termux](https://termux.net). The app is available for Android 5.0 and newer on both Google Play and F-Droid.

Writing .tex files and compiling them works just as on a normal linux distribution, editors such as vim and emacs are available.

It's open source as well, check out the [github repos](https://github.com/termux).

Answer (score 3):

The geek solution is to install [Jack Palevich's Android terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en) and then [Kevin Boone's Kbox2](http://kevinboone.net/kbox2_onebox.html), then you can install a `LaTeX` distribution, I personally made my own by extracting only essential packages from `TeXLive` archives on `ctan.org` and picking the `pdftex` binary that comes with [texportal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lah.texportal&hl=en). I don't know if `TeXLive` for android is based on the same trick. It works great for me but only in urgency case because I have no computer at home, only a cheap tablet ([mpman mp888](http://www.mpmaneurope.com/en/products/internet-tablets-14/dual-core-tablet-mp888-290/))... and of course no root needed to all this. Maybe [vim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch&hl=en) can make the workflow better than editing with [droidedit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aor.droidedit&hl=en) and switch to the terminal to compile (it is what i'm doing)

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time figuring this out...

My approach:

- `VerbTeX Pro` for editing latex documents, which gives a nice android-friendly UI.
- GNURoot Debian with `openbox` and `tightvncserver` as a UI which can be viewed in `VNC reader` for automatic compilation and preview.
  Briefly, I installed `texlive-full` in here and I'm using `latexmk` to automatically recompile my pdf when I save changes in `VertTeX Pro`.
  The resulting pdf will be automatically updated if your previewing it in `evince`.

The end result is that every time I press save in `VerbTeX Pro`, I can just `Alt Tab` to `VNCViewer` which will already be showing a preview of the latest changes I made.
I'm not sure how nice this is on a phone, but on a tablet with keyboard, its quite convenient.

The guide on how to do this is a bit long for an answer here... so you can check my blog [here](https://rtbecard.github.io/2018/03/24/GNURoot-Debian-and-openbox-on-Yoga-Book.html) if you want all the details on how to set this up.

With some options in `latexmk`, I'm sure you can compile with XeLaTeX.