# Can you run mk4ht on iPad or Android?

Tags: tex4ht, html, ipad, android

I need to create html files from tex using mk4ht on an iPad or an Android tablet... Is there any way to run mk4ht on iOS or Android? Preferably without requiring Internet connection, but if that's not possible then I suppose with Internet connection would be OK too.

Comment: I wonder if [this project](http://texpadapp.com/2012/09/19/latex-ported-to-ipad/) has anything to offer?

Comment: [This question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87520/34551) on how to install LaTeX on such devices seems strongly related. [mk4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/make4ht) is a wrapper for [tex4ht](http://tug.org/tex4ht), which requires a working LaTeX installation. Do you have a working LaTeX environment on your iPad / Android?

Comment: If online is ok then you can use Overleaf, it supports `tex4ht`.