# Texportal on Android

Tags: texlive, android

I read your comment on the TeXPortal-site ([How to install TeX on Android phones?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87520/how-to-install-tex-on-android-phones)). I would also like to have `TeX` on my Android tablet, and thus would like to know what exactly you did that it worked.

I downloaded `TeXLive` on a `Linux` device, copied it to `/sdcard/texlive` (I have a folder on my device now that is named `TeXLive` on my sdcard. it contains the folders `texmf-dist`, `-var`, `-local`, `tlpkg` etc.) on my tablet (without the docs but with the source), installed TeXPortal, and it still gives me a `missing texmf.cnf`.
Even though I changed the `TEXMFROOT` to `/sdcard/texlive`, and tried changing it in `texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf` also to that value, and even tried changing the directory, which was given in TeXPortal-Settings (`storage/.../data/lah.texportal/files`) as the `TEXMF` Root to `sdcard/texive` - nothing did help.

It says that `kpathsea` is missing, installs it, and then comes the missing `texmf.cnf`.

Is it necessary to have the device rooted? As far as I understood, this was not necessary.

Thanks for some advice ;)
Best regards
J

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: OK, I kind of solved it.

I installed the apk from this website: http://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/.

this installs a terminal, in settings i installed texlive (maybe that was not necessary, but it confirmed it).

I set the TEXMFROOT in sdcard/texlive/texmf.cnf to sdcard/texlive, and reinstalled texportal.

After that, I compiled a document, it started installing missing packages, and finally I got a PDF :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the question is solved by the comment.