# Texlive on Android

Tags: texlive, android

I have seen a few people asking how to install texlive on android using an apk from https://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/, eventually figuring out how to set it up. I have tried to install texlive on my device without any success and was wondering if anyone would mind giving step by step instructions on how to get it done.

I got as far as installing the apk and selecting install texlive from the terminal. After that nothing happens for a while and then a popup appears saying that texlive has stopped working. My end goal is to use the vim provided with terminal ide and be able to compile from its command line.

Comment: Related: [How to install TeX on android phones?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87520)