# How to install TeX Live on Android tablet 4.2.2?

Tags: texlive, android

I'm reading this
[How to install TeX on Android phones?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87520/how-to-install-tex-on-android-phones)
 post and I can't install TeX Live on Android 4.2.2 and I have `tl4a-2013-06-10.tar.xz`, `TL4A.apk`, `tl4a-2013-06-18.tar.xz`, and `texmf.cnf` on my tablet.

Comment: do you have the `unknown sources` unlocked on your tablet? otherwise you can't install apk not coming from the market

Comment: TL4A.apk already installed. but i can't install packages and use.

Comment: some specific error is displayed?

Comment: I have no error actually i need an editor as in computer like Texstudio or bibtex maker.

Comment: According to the [site](https://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/) an IDE will be present in the next version. Maybe now you have to write your files in other ways and then compile

Comment: It's impossible to help without more information. (Not that I can anyway, but I'm just saying.)

Comment: could you tell me how can i use after install. after install apk file  i just see this [site](http://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/) picture i mean at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Now I am installing TeX Live for Android.  I began installation 6 months ago; now I can make PDF and DVI of English LaTeX files, but the installation is still incomplete.
I have Android 4.2.2 on an unrooted tablet with 16M internal memory.  *Unknown sources* option is unchecked in Security options of tablet, *Verify apps* is checked (I changed *Unknown sources* option; AFAIR I disabled it before installation of TeX Live, but I am not sure).

1. I installed *TeXLive for Android* from Google *Play Store*.  The installation was not complete.  The binaries were not uncompressed (I could see that by verifying the available space on internal storage).  As a result of installation of *TeXLive for Android*, I got *Terminal Emulator for Android* with necessary libraries ready to installation of TeX.
2. Installing the binaries: I used tl4a-2013-06-18.tar.xz  Now it is available on  https://code.google.com/p/texlive-for-android/downloads/  I unpacked the files from tl4a-2013-06-18.tar\bin directory of the archive to /data/data/texlive.androidport/bin directory on the tablet. (To see what directory install binaries to, I verified PATH variable:

   `ua_a110@android:/ $ echo $PATH`
   `/vendor/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/data/data/texlive.androidport/bin-base:/data/data/texlive.androidport/bin`

The other story is how to extract files. I unpacked the archive on Windows PC to SD-card, plugged SD-card into tablet PC, and copied files at bin directory with `cat` and `chmod 500`. Probably there is a better way.)

3. Installing texmf tree. I tried to install the tree onto plugged-in SD-card, but I failed.  C. MA suggests installation to /sdcard/texlive , and make changes to texmf.cnf. I installed the texmf tree to ~/texmf, which is one of default directories where tex searches files.
   I do not remember where I got `texmf.cnf` file from. Probably from I got it from `tetex` distribution or from `kpathsee` distribution. Copy `texmf.cnf` to `/sdcard/texlive`
   The easiest way was to copy texmf tree completely if there is available space. But I copied individual packages, some from texlive, some from CTAN, some from living MikTeX.
4. Compiling tex formats.  I have installed LaTeX from sources. But the easier way is (if texlive tree installed)

   `pdftex -ini latex.ltx`

and then copy latex.fmt file to a directory where tex searches for format files (maybe to `~/texmf/web2c/` directory?).  I copied `latex.fmt` to `~/formats/` directory.

I did not tried wheter `latex.fmt` from other tex distribution works.

5. Creating shortcuts. Verify that you do not have `latex` and `pdflatex` files in tex binary directory.  Then I created two files `latex` and `pdflatex` with in tex binaries directory with following content

   /data/data/texlive.androidport/bin/latex:
      `pdftex -output-format=dvi -fmt=/data/data/texlive.androidport/app_HOME/formats/latex.fmt $*`

   /data/data/texlive.androidport/bin/pdflatex:
      `pdftex -output-format=pdf -fmt=/data/data/texlive.androidport/app_HOME/formats/latex.fmt $*`

(Each file contains one line, starts with `pdftex` and ends with `$*`. Here `/data/data/texlive.androidport/bin` is tex binary directory, and `/data/data/texlive.androidport/app_HOME/formats` is a directory where I copied `latex.fmt`.)

Then I made this two files executable with `chmod 500`.

6. TODO Compile formats for `METAFONT`.
   Configure `dvipdfmx` and `dvips`.
   I have not done that yet.

I have copied PDF fonts from the other TEX distribution (MiKTeX). Now I can make DVI and PDF files of TEX file without generating new fonts. I can read PDF files with *Adobe Reader*. I cannot do anything with DVI files because `dvipdfm` and `dvips` are not configured yet.

Note that *TeXLive for Android* package does not contain an editor.  But you can use and an editor from another app package.  I use Kingsoft Office.  One minor disadvantage is that it cannot open files with .tex extension.  So I have to rename .tex files to .txt for editing.  There are some specialized LaTeX editors in Google *Play Store*.  I hope they can work side-by-side with *TeXLive for Android*: Author .tex with the editor, and then "convert" it to .pdf with *TeXLive for Android*, and then view it with your favourite PDF viewer.  But I have not tried specialized TeX editors yet.