# Can I write with the pencil on a tablet and get a document .tex? What tablet you recommend?

Tags: cross-referencing, android, tablet

I ever saw in a old version of tablet galaxy note that you can create a pdf writing on a tablet, however I do not know if I can obtain an file .tex.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151412/how-to-install-tex-live-on-android-tablet-4-2-2

Comment: @user29999 Probably did you mean something like Nebo http://www.myscript.com/nebo/?lang=en-us which allows to convert handwritten notes in plain text files?

Comment: Arianna Angeletti. Rest only to know if it produces an file .tex or only a pdf file

Comment: According to http://www.myscript.com/nebo/?lang=en-us you could not get .tex file, but you could export plain text files
and import them in the app "Latex Master File Creator"  (look at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ariang.android.txts2tex ) which incidentally I developed in Android.